# IE8 ignoring CSS when a user is logged on

Tags: php, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I have a custom WP plugin that allows logged in users to vote on custom Polls. I have this working fine in `Firefox 26` and `IE 10`, but it is not displaying correctly in `IE 8` when a user is logged in (which sadly we have to use due to the use of Terminal Server 2003).

Please note though that when a user is logged out in `IE 8`, the Poll displays just fine (see images below).

My first step here was to use the Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>, yuk!), and with Debugging enabled, no errors are reported in the console.

However, it did throw up a peculiar issue; The required style sheet is listed in the dropdown on the CSS tab when I am logged out, but it is not when I am logged in. However, this CSS is 100% definatly referenced in the source (it must be, everything is fine in `IE 10` and `Firefox 26`)

I'm stumped as to what may be causing this and what I can do to fix the issue, so any pointers would be gratefully received. Thanks.

http://pastebin.com/PVJqRGVP - Source when I am logged out
http://pastebin.com/PG9uHZ2P - Source when I am logged in
http://pastebin.com/5fuBhdB1 - The relevant CSS (voting-front-end.css)

As an example, here is what the Poll looks like IE8 when a user is logged out (correct) -

[image]

And here is what it looks like in IE8 when a user is logged in -

[image]

Comment: I noticed you said that the style sheet is referenced in the source, but didnt say if it actually was, you only assumed it was because it was working within firefox and IE10. Could you check the source in IE8 to make sure that the code is definitely there? The reason I say this is that some browsers will correct simple code errors for you (like not closing a tag, or missing something out), where as IE8 does none of that. So you may be able to find what is broken by looking in the IE8 source.

Comment: @Joe - I have checked, the style sheet is referenced in `IE 8`. Also, it's enqueued by Wordpress, so any issues with code errors would be shared by other style sheets called in this manner, which is not the case. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the code displaying the bars is html5, and that html5 shiv (or similar) is being loaded when a user is logged in? Without seeing the source code of the logged in page and logged out page its a bit hard to tell without taking a random guess really.

Comment: @Joe - I've added the full source for when I am both logged in and out to a Pastebin, and updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Which stylesheet is responsible for the poll results css?

Comment: @Joe - `voting-front-end.css`, it's declared in the footer (why Wordpress puts it there, I don't know). I'm just making a Pastebin for that as well, I'll update the question in a moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older IE have a limitation that they only process the first **31** embedded stylesheets – every stylesheet that comes after that just gets ignored.

And counting the `<link rel=stylesheet>` *before* your `voting-front-end.css` I come up with 28 of those in your not-logged-in source code, and – drumroll – **31** in your logged-in source code.

---

So see to it that you limit the number of embedded stylesheets – by aggregating multiple of those into a single resource. You should do that anyway for performance reasons, because a high number of individual HTTP requests to load external resources such as stylesheets slow the initial load of the page down.

Comment: @CBore - I never know that, and that is (unsurprisingly for IE!) quite shocking. I'll see what I can do to consolidate CSS, but a fair bit of it needs to stay separate as it's used for various different plugins. I'm not too worried about performance in this instance either as it's for a local intranet, and the server can easily handle the limited requests it gets.

Comment: @CBore - Ok, so tested and validated, your answer is indeed correct. I see a couple of errors that I can fix to remove duplicate calls, that should solve the problem for now, and I'll take on board what you say about combining multiple style sheets, and I'll loot to do this more in the future.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, something I never knew there. Not surprising IE had something like this with it really.